# add a parameter name to a json file with jq

Tags: json, bash, jq

I am trying to make my json file that looks like this

```
{
    "database_details": {
    "age": "false",
    "help": "xxxx",
    "host": "",
    "servername": "fra02",
    "db_name": "config_tools",
    "pass": "xxxx",
    "user": "default",

  },
  {
     "age": "false",
    "help": "xxxx",
    "host": "",
    "servername": "fra03",
    "db_name": "config_tools",
    "pass": "xxxx",
    "user": "default",
  }
}
```

to look like

```
{
"database_details": {
"fra02":{
    "age": "false",
    "help": "xxxx",
    "host": "",
    "servername": "fra02",
    "db_name": "config_tools",
    "pass": "xxxx",
    "user": "default",
},
"fra03": {
  "age": "false",
    "help": "xxxx",
    "host": "",
    "servername": "fra02",
    "db_name": "config_tools",
    "pass": "xxxx",
    "user": "default",
}
}
}
```

I have tried jq but not sure if that is the right approach?
I have thought about using awk or sed but not sure that is the cleanest route?

Comment: To start, both of your code samples are not valid JSON. So that will be a problem for [tag:jq].

Comment: If this is representative of your real data, it's not JSON, and the title and tagging are both misleading. Whether your inputs are streams of JSON objects, or complete JSON documents, &c. are all critical details; it's not enough to just sketch something that's vaguely close.

Comment: Yes i just pasted a snippet and it is missing a few {

Answer (score 1):

Assuming valid JSON like

```
{
  "database_details": [
     {
       "age": "false",
       "help": "xxxx",
       "host": "",
       "servername": "fra02",
       "db_name": "config_tools",
       "pass": "xxxx",
       "user": "default"
     },
     {
       "age": "false",
       "help": "xxxx",
       "host": "",
       "servername": "fra03",
       "db_name": "config_tools",
       "pass": "xxxx",
       "user": "default"
     }
  ]
}
```

you can use the filter

```
.database_details |= (map({key: .servername, value: .}) | from_entries)
```

The  array associated with `database_details` is turned into an array of key/value pairs, which `from_entries` turns into a new object that `|=` assigns back to the key `database_details` in the original object.